# How do I query a column where a specific number does not exist in any of the rows of that column

Tags: sql, string, average, aggregate-functions

I have `ID | Name | Salary` with types as `Integer | String | Integer` respectively.

I need to query the avg of all the rows of the Salary column, and then query the avg of all the rows of the Salary column again, but if any of those rows contain 0, remove 0 from those numbers, and calculate the avg.

So like if Salary returns `1420, 2006, 500`, the next query should return `142, 26, 5`. Then I calculate the avg of the subsequent numbers not containing 0.

I tried googling my specific problem but am not finding anything close to  a solution. I'm not looking for an answer too much more than a shove in the right direction.

**My Thoughts**

- Maybe I need to convert the `integer` data type to a `varchar` or string then remove the '0' digit from there, then convert back?
- Maybe I need to create a temporary table from the first tables results, and insert them, just without 0?

Any ideas? Hope I was clear. Thanks!

Sample table data:

```
ID | Name     | Salary
---+----------+-------
1  | Kathleen | 1420
2  | Bobby    |  690
3  | Cat      |  500
```

Now I need to query the above table but with the 0's removed from the salary rows

```
ID | Name     | Salary
---+----------+-------
1  | Kathleen | 142
2  | Bobby    |  69
3  | Cat      |   5
```

Comment: Why are you removing the zeroes? Why would you got from 2006 to 26?

Comment: My problem requires me to do so.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Got it, updated

Comment: What about 101, should it be 11?

Comment: I'd go with "Thought 1".

Comment: Yeah, like 101 would become 11. Appreciate the input!

Comment: It's an unusual requirement to say the least. But removing zeroes in this way *is* a string operation, so your first thought is correct. Whether you use an intermediary table is a matter of choice (perhaps guided by performance).

Comment: PLease tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove all `0`s from your numbers, then take a numeric average of the result. As you are foreseeing, this requires mixing string and numeric operations.

The actual syntax will vary across databases. In MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle, you should be able to do:

```
select avg(replace(salary, '0', '') + 0) as myavg
from mytable
```

This involves two steps of implicit conversion: `replace()` forces string context, and `+ 0` turns the result back to a number. In SQL Server, you will get an integer result - if you want a decimal average instead, you might need to add a decimal value instead - so `+ 0.0` instead of `+ 0`.

In Postgres, where implicit conversion is not happening as easily, you would use explicit casts:

```
select avg(replace(salary::text, '0', '')::int) as myavg
from mytable
```

This returns a decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
select avg(salary), avg(case when salary <> 0 then salary end)
from t;
```

or do you want division?

```
select id, name, floor(salary / 10)
from t;
```

This produces the results you specify but it has nothing to do with "average"s.